# Is there a way to associate two Google Voice numbers to the same cellphone?

Tags: google-workspace, google-voice, google-account

I have a Gmail account and a Google Apps account.  I have setup a Google Voice number and associated it with my mobile phone for personal use.

I want to setup a Google Voice account for business and associate it with my Google Apps account and associate it with my same mobile phone.

The idea is that I carry one phone, and business contacts call one number, while personal contacts call another.

Has anyone found a workaround for this?  When I try to setup on one account, it disables the other Google Voice number.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can do this but you have to set up the mobile number as either `work` or `home` on your Google Voice accounts.

As soon as you set it up as a `mobile` on an account it will disable the other account.

By not setting it as mobile, I think you may lose any SMS functionality.

Comment: I have one Google Account that uses one number, and my Gmail account using another number.  Both forward to the same cellular phone, except one is marked as `Home` and the other is marked as `Work`.  I just tested and verified that this is indeed a working solution.  Thanks!

Comment: As of today, this method NO LONGER works. I just tried it.

Answer (score -2):

Use google voice for personal let the people you want know that #.
Use the cell phone number for work when you ditch job you ditch number.
Anyone close enough to get google number still can reach you! Because you just set up GV with new cell number!

Ya! I know you want one number for work so it is convenient. But listen if the person is that important then they can have your personal GV.  Otherwise they get the standard three number business contact info. What is so unacceptable about that?

Comment: I purposely asked about using *two* Google Voice numbers. This doesn't really answer the question nor does it solve the problem; however, I appreciate your input.